# jQuery Revert to Default Class on Mouseout

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery .hover() to change the class of another element.  When cat is hovered, the class "cat" is added to the div "photo".  When dog is hovered, the class "dog" is added to the div "photo".  Cat, Dog, and Giraffe can all be active at any given time.  On mouseout, I need the photo div to revert back to the class of whatever the active element might be.

```
<ul>
     <li class="cat active">Cat</li>
    <li class="dog">Dog</li>
    <li class="giraffe">Giraffe</li>
</ul>

<div id="photo" class="cat"></div>
```

My hover script

```
$('li.cat').hover(function(){
    $('#photo').removeClass().addClass('cat');
});

$('li.dog').hover(function(){
    $('#photo').removeClass().addClass('dog');
});

$('li.giraffe').hover(function(){
    $('#photo').removeClass().addClass('giraffe');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general solution would simply be to iterate over the list of classes that the "active" element has, look for the one you're expecting, and apply that one. However, if you can guarantee that the classList of the `li`s will never be anything other than `dog|cat|giraffe` plus an optional `active`, then you can simplify by just removing the `active` class.

Also, you can optimize your code by having a generic handler function rather than a separate one for each `li`. Finally, the `hover()` jQuery method takes two arguments: a function to execute on mouse in, and one to execute on mouse out. [Fiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/TxJk5/)

```js
var getPhotoClassesFromElement = function ($el) {
    var otherClasses = $el[0].className.replace(/\s*active\s*/, '');
    return otherClasses;
};

var handlerIn = function (e) {
    var $el = $(e.target);
    var photoClass = getPhotoClassesFromElement($el);
    $('#photo').removeClass().addClass(photoClass);
};

var handlerOut = function (e) {
    var $el = $(e.target);
    var photoClass = getPhotoClassesFromElement($('li.active'));
    $('#photo').removeClass().addClass(photoClass);
};

$('li').hover(handlerIn, handlerOut);
```